# Exercise: Prove some properties about some numbers of a set.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $W=\left\{w = \dfrac{1+\dfrac{iy}{2}}{1-\dfrac{iy}{2}} \ \colon \ y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$. Then show that:

1. $w\in W \Longrightarrow |w|=1$
2. $-1\not\in W$ .

What I've done so far: I took the definition of the elements in $W$ and brought it into the form $a+ib$, then I tried to calculate $|w|=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=\cdots=1$. However, I never managed to get 1.

Is there an easy way to prove these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the numerator and denominator of
$$\frac{1+\frac{iy}{2}}{1-\frac{iy}{2}}.$$
Both have the same absolute value, hence the quotient has absolute value 1.

Further, $-1$ is not element of your set because that would imply that the numerator is the negation of the denominator. Since both have positive real part (namely $1$), this isn't the case.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this nice and short proof! Very good!